# When I run python portable, sometimes it crashes, sometimes it doesnt

Tags: python, crash, startup, portability, portable-python

When I run Python portable, sometimes it crashes, sometimes it does not. I am not sure if it is clashing with another program or if it is something else. I can *never* reproduce this situation. Can anyone help?

Comment: I know these are hard problems and I sympathise, but you're going to need more than that. Are there tracebacks? What are you running on Python portable? Currently this is just too broad.

Comment: Are you always running Python portable on the same computer? With the same script?

Answer (score 1):

First i would start it after a fresh reboot and look which services run directly after reboot and after first, second... programm start.

Then looking at the ram acn be intresting. Maybe you got a ram leak/overflow.

Then i would compare theese results with a program start, when you did ur typical stuff (office, games, internet, videos)

Do you maybe run the x86 version on a 64bit computer? Is your ram generally ok (memtest), on which core does it run for you (multicore processor), Wchich version do you run (is it the newest)?Do you get the same results on a different Computer?

Perhaps some of this helps, yours JungerIslaender